# Advantage Database Server INSERT/UPDATE queries performance issues

Tags: .net, performance, database-connection, advantage-database-server

I'm using the [Advantage Database Server v10](http://www.sybase.com/products/databasemanagement/advantagedatabaseserver) and the corresponding ADO.NET provider. I found that `AdsConnection.Close` takes significant amount of time after an executing of `INSERT/UPDATE` queries.

For example this sample

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var openTimer = new Stopwatch();
        var closeTimer = new Stopwatch();
        var executeTimer = new Stopwatch();

        for (int ix = 0; ix < 100; ix++)
        {
            openTimer.Start();
            using (var cnn = new AdsConnection(
                @"data source=...; ServerType=remote; user id=admin; password=..."))
            {
                cnn.Open();
                openTimer.Stop();


                executeTimer.Start();
                using (var cmd = cnn.CreateCommand())
                {
                    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT MAX(colUGId) FROM tblUserGroup";

                    var id = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar() + 1;

                    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tblUserGroup (colUGId, colName, colDesc) VALUES (:id, :name, :desc)";
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("id", id);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("name", "Name " + id);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("desc", "Description " + id);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                executeTimer.Stop();


                closeTimer.Start();
            }
            closeTimer.Stop();
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Open: {0}; Execute: {1}; Close: {2}", openTimer.Elapsed, executeTimer.Elapsed, closeTimer.Elapsed);
    }
}
```

outputs:

```
Open: 00:00:00.2361612; Execute: 00:00:15.3849932; Close: 00:00:05.4333431
```

It is very interesting why 100 INSERT operations in the simple table with trivial indexes and without any triggers take 15 seconds. But the most important question: why `Close` takes so long?

Any ideas?

***UPDATE***

Just tried the same with the SQL Server. It runs on a different workstation, which is a bit faster then the workstation with Advantage. Anyway, I can see that the connection pool works (in the case of SQL Server) good:

```
Open: 00:00:00.2279668; Execute: 00:00:00.0189551; Close: 00:00:00.0003487
```

Comment: You are creating and disposing the AdsConnection class 100 times. Why not just open it once, execute all your inserts, then close?

Comment: @BradM I thought, that the connection pool was invented to save me from doing it

Comment: ie. is right, connection pooling should solve exactly that, see also: http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/webhelp/Advantage11.1/dotnet_advantage_net_data_provider_and_connection_pooling.htm

Answer (score 2):

The 15 seconds is definitely long.  Since you mention indexes, I'm sure you have the necessary index, but make sure that there is an index on `colUGId`.  If that index does not exist, the `select max` query will require a full table scan each time it is run.  If the table is relatively large, that could be very costly.

While the connection pooling does eliminate the cost of obtaining a new connection each time through the loop, the code as shown is causing the table involved to be fully closed with each iteration.  So the server ends up opening and closing the table every single time through the loop (assuming no other user has it open while doing this test).  That would definitely add to the cost, although I don't know why it would result in the reported times.

While it does not answer the question, I ran the exact code above (with the connection string modified of course) and produced these numbers:

```
Open: 00:00:00.8909295; Execute: 00:00:01.4729069; Close: 00:00:01.4211188
```

Out of curiosity, I then moved the obtaining of the connection outside the loop and ran it again.  This allowed the table to remain open between executions.  It resulted in these numbers:

```
Open: 00:00:00.1073400; Execute: 00:00:00.0802774; Close: 00:00:00.0270569
```

One other thing to note with the code as written is it cannot reuse any prepared statements.  In particular, the same command object is used for both the SELECT and the INSERT.  This results in the statements being parsed and semantic checked every iteration.  This is certainly not a big thing but it can add up.  I ran the test again using two command objects and got these numbers:

```
Open: 00:00:00.0835544; Execute: 00:00:00.0567687; Close: 00:00:00.0267799
```